# Can't kill a zombie Collection in Backbone project

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, zombie-process

In my Backbone project, I have a router which creates a View, `viewA`.

`viewA` creates a subview, `viewA2` as part of its render process.

`viewA2` has a collection which contains Card models, but I also declare another Collection of Tag models in `viewA2` 's `initialize()` function. Like so:

```
initialize: function() {

        this.tagCollection = new tagModels.TagCollection();

        this.tagCollection.fetch({
            reset: true
        });
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change:tags', this.updateContentList);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset remove', this.updateContentList);
        this.listenTo(this.tagCollection, 'reset', this.resetTags);
        this.listenTo(this.tagCollection, 'add', this.addTag);
        this.listenTo(this.tagCollection, 'remove', this.removeTag);
}
```

Now at some point the router switches pages in the app, gets rid of `viewA` and replaces it with `viewB`. Before switching to `viewB` I do:

```
viewA2.tagCollection.reset();
viewA2.remove();
viewA.remove();
```

According to the Backbone extension in Chrome, both `viewA` and `viewA2` are destroyed, but `viewA2.tagCollection` still exists, even though it has been reset and contains no models. Every time I switch views, another Collection is added.

Why doesn't the empty Collection die? The View which it was a property of no longer exists. I've also tried `viewA2.stopListening()` before removing `viewA2`.

I realise that one way of bypassing this problem is to create the `tagCollection` further up the chain, for example in the router, and pass a reference to it to `viewA`, and from there to `viewA2`. This might be a better design for my app., but it feels clumsy passing references up and down the chain of views. Should I be taking that approach anyway?

Finally. I'm aware that listening to two Collections in one View may not be best practice. If that is deemed to be a major issue I can give more details as to why I've done it that way.

Comment: Excuse the clumsy reference, but have you tried shooting it in the head?

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville it might come to that... :/

Comment: Does  `delete viewA2.tagCollection` get rid of it?

Comment: @ivarni - No, that doesn't do it.

Comment: Removed the [tag:google-chrome-extension] tag. Do not use it unless it's about extension development.

Comment: My issue came about through the use of Google Chrome extension, so I wanted to draw attention to that. Can you recommend another tag?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have been distracted by the output of the Backbone Chrome extension. It scores out Views when they are removed, but doesn't do the same for Collections - at least in this case - when they are destroyed.

My zombie Collections were triggering the same events multiple times, because they were hanging around in the background. It turns out that this was in fact fixed by removing `viewA2` before removing `viewA`.

The output of Backbone Chrome led me to believe that the Collections were still in memory, but the events are no longer triggered mulitple times since removing the subview before the View.

I also confirmed the non-existence of the old Collections by trying to write Collection details to the console after using javascript `delete` on them. (Thanks @ivarni.) The deleted collection was undefined, but there was still an apparently valid entry for it in the Backbone Chrome extension.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to say that I didn't believe you when you said `delete` didn't remove it :)